# Executar comando somente após o término do for - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Preciso pegar a distância percorrida por um veiculo nos últimos 3 dias e exibir no gráfico. Para isso, faço um `for` e vou calculando a distancia percorrida e salvando em um *array* `(arrayKmDayData)`:

```
 arrayKmDayData.push(Math.abs((response[response.length - 1].distanceTraveled - response[0].distanceTraveled)/1000));
```

Depois de preencher esse *array* com a distancia dos 3 dias, os exibo no gráfico:

```
      $scope.labels = arrayKmDayLabel,
      $scope.data = [
        arrayKmDayData
      ];
```

O problema é que antes mesmo de terminar o `for`, meu script já está chamando a parte de exibir o gráfico, ou seja, ele executa o for pela primeira vez e já exibe o gráfico, depois executa o `for` pela segunda vez e reexibe o gráfico e por ultimo, executa o `for` pela 3ª vez e exibe o gráfico novamente.

Como fazer para exibir o gráfico somente após terminar o for?

Segue o código:

```
for(var i = -2; i <= 0; i ++){
    day = getKmDate(i);
    date = new Date(day[0]);
    arrayKmDayLabel.push(date.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR"));

    var query = new $kinvey.Query();   
    query.equalTo('idColetor', arraySelectedItem[0]);   
    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('tsmilliseconds', day[0]);  
    query.lessThan('tsmilliseconds', day[1]);  
    query.descending('tsmilliseconds');            
    var promise = $kinvey.DataStore.find('myCollection', query); 
    promise.then(function(response) {  
      arrayKmDayData.push(Math.abs((response[response.length - 1].distanceTraveled - response[0].distanceTraveled)/1000));

    });

  }

      $scope.labels = arrayKmDayLabel,
      $scope.data = [
        arrayKmDayData
      ];
```

Agradeço qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Qual a parte do seu código que exibe o gráfico?

Comment: @SamirBraga no HTML tem: `<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" 
     chart-legend="true" chart-series="series" chart-click="onClick"></canvas>` e no javascript `$scope.labels = arrayKmDayLabel,
      $scope.data = [
        arrayKmDayData
      ];`

Comment: @SamirBraga estou usando o chart.js

Comment: Você poderia colocar o `$scope.labels = arrayKmDayLabel, $scope.data = [ arrayKmDayData ];` para ser executado em um `if (i == 0)` dentro do `for`, já que este é o fim do `loop`. O que você acha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está alimentando o gráfico antes dos dados serem recuperados. O correto seria alimentar os dados no gráfico apenas quando os promises fossem resolvidos. Caso você esteja usando uma biblioteca de promises, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
var proms = [];
for(var i = -2; i <= 0; i ++){
    day = getKmDate(i);
    date = new Date(day[0]);
    arrayKmDayLabel.push(date.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR"));

    var query = new $kinvey.Query();   
    query.equalTo('idColetor', arraySelectedItem[0]);   
    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('tsmilliseconds', day[0]);  
    query.lessThan('tsmilliseconds', day[1]);  
    query.descending('tsmilliseconds');            
    var promise = $kinvey.DataStore.find('myCollection', query); 
    promise.then(function(response) {  
       arrayKmDayData.push(Math.abs((response[response.length - 1].distanceTraveled - response[0].distanceTraveled)/1000));
    });

    proms.push(promise);
}

Promise.all(proms)
.then(function() {
  // valores são lançados apenas quando todos os promises são resolvidos
  $scope.labels = arrayKmDayLabel,
  $scope.data = [
    arrayKmDayData
  ];
});
```

caso você não esteja usando uma biblioteca de promises, então o melhor é usar um contador.

```
var counter = 0;
for(var i = -2; i <= 0; i ++){
    day = getKmDate(i);
    date = new Date(day[0]);
    arrayKmDayLabel.push(date.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR"));

    var query = new $kinvey.Query();   
    query.equalTo('idColetor', arraySelectedItem[0]);   
    query.greaterThanOrEqualTo('tsmilliseconds', day[0]);  
    query.lessThan('tsmilliseconds', day[1]);  
    query.descending('tsmilliseconds');            
    var promise = $kinvey.DataStore.find('myCollection', query); 
    promise.then(function(response) {  
        arrayKmDayData.push(Math.abs((response[response.length - 1].distanceTraveled - response[0].distanceTraveled)/1000));
        counter++;
        if (counter===3) {
           $scope.labels = arrayKmDayLabel,
           $scope.data = [
             arrayKmDayData
           ];
        }
    });

  }
```